# Will iRig connect my electronic guitar to my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, music, accessories, garageband

I know Apogee iJam can do this, but it's a little expensive for me. iRig can connect a guitar to iOS devices, but will iRig connect a guitar to a MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Macbook Pro has the single 3.5mm jack that can take input and output then iRig should work just fine for you.
Someone asked [a similar question here](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/H2169VC/A?pqid=Q7TXXFJK2TF7C4KP74XYU7JF9KC7DCAP7). If you're looking for something ultra cheap you could always get a 1/4" to 3.5mm adaptor to plug your guitar into your Mac. I did this for a very long time until I could afford higher quality hardware. These things run as low as $2 at some places, [here is one](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?pq=guitar%20to%203.5mm&hl=en&sugexp=epsu2&qe=MS80IHRvIDMuNW1t&qesig=L6nH1TNm5za3iUaBFyfURQ&pkc=AFgZ2tkHYYGjD67Mvk4KKIt4zkJZft7UiGxlX8MQKX5VYfn87IQRccGOAIK5K9ogallHwANPl0Al_zU_-MhKq-wV3xc7jaiCzA&cp=3&gs_id=1t&xhr=t&q=1/4%20to%203.5mm%20adapter&client=safari&rls=en&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1279&bih=680&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=612965013226683404&sa=X&ei=6HUrT-LRB6GxiQK_kqWzCg&sqi=2&ved=0CLcBEPMCMAI#ps-sellers) for example. Hope this helps!

Comment: the user reference says that the jack is for output ...